# C# UserControl Not and Yes with Text

Tags: c#, user-controls, overflow

The Default is No Checkbox

When I run the program and Click the Yes Checkbox the program overflowed

```
private void checkEdit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkEdit2.Checked = false;
            textEdit1.Enabled = true;
            answered = true;
            optional = textEdit1.Text;

            if (!checkEdit1.Checked)
            {
                checkEdit1.Checked = true;
                checkEdit2.Checked = false;
                textEdit1.Enabled = true;
                optional = textEdit1.Text;
            }

        }

        private void checkEdit2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkEdit1.Checked = false;
            textEdit1.Enabled = false;
            answered = false;

            if (!checkEdit2.Checked)
            {
                checkEdit2.Checked = true;
                checkEdit1.Checked = false;
                textEdit1.Enabled = false;
                answered = false;
            }

        }
```

What you think is the error ?

Comment: The program "overflowed?" What does that mean?

Comment: Why are you using checkboxes when radio buttons would seem to be the clearer choice?

Comment: @JesseJ: Computers can get over-excited too you know

Comment: Also, you should maybe specify what the "Yes Chekcbox" is...

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Comment: If i click yes the Checkbox Checked is true, and No Checked is false, and if i click no the checkbox checked is true and Yes checked is false

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `Click` event you should use the `CheckedChanged` event in this way:

```
checkEdit1.CheckedChenged += new EventHandler(checkEdit1_CheckedChanged);
checkEdit2.CheckedChenged += new EventHandler(checkEdit2_CheckedChanged);
```

---

```
private void checkEdit1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkEdit1.Checked == checkEdit2.Checked)
      checkEdit2.Checked = !checkEdit.Checked;
}

private void checkEdit2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(checkEdit1.Checked == checkEdit2.Checked)
      checkEdit2.Checked = !checkEdit.Checked;
}
```

But the best way in this case is to use a group of radio buttons.

Comment: already done that, but still same problem... anyway thank you for your reply.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those methods are wired up to `checkEdit1` and `checkEdit2` I would advise that you don't make a change to `checkEdit1` in `checkEdit1_Click` as it has already changed - only modify the state of the alternate.

However, when you modify the state of the other, unless you're careful, you're going to get called back.  Eventually the computer gives up -- the overflow!

As mentioned in a comment by @Cyborgx37, radio buttons are the better UX choice here!

A possible solution, bind a single method to the OnClick to BOTH checkboxes:

```
private bool internallyUpdating = false;

private void CheckboxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( !internallyUpdating )
    {
        // Prevent subsequent changes
        internallyUpdating = true;

        // Exchange 'checked' state
        if ( sender == checkEdit1 )
        {
            checkEdit2.Checked = !checkEdit2.Checked;
        } 
        else // if (sender == checkEdit2)
        {
            checkEdit1.Checked = !checkEdit1.Checked;
        }

        // other logic here..

        // restore 'on change' functionality.
        internallyUpdating = false;
    }
```